# Is it true that embedded graphics cards reduce the CPU's performance?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, performance, cpu, bus

Consider the Intel HD Graphics. The video card resides inside the cpu die and uses ordinary system RAM. Therefore, it uses up Front Side Bus and Northbridge bandwidth. Therefore, accessing the main memory - the biggest bottleneck in modern computing, becomes event slower.

But this technology gets put on all newer desktop Intel CPUs. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing price. Adding a separate graphics card increases the price, while a lot off users will do just fine with the integrated graphics card.

Comment: No; It is 100% false.  Yes; older generations of platform it could have an effect but that had not been true since Pent 4 which was released in 2004

Answer (score 4):

FSB and Northbridge are obsolete technologies. All modern systems work on the basis of a point-to-point interconnect (Intel's QuickPath Interconnect, AMD's HyperTransport etc.) which doesn't have a 'hub' like a Northbridge or a bus with limited global bandwidth as was the case with FSB.

This alone reduces the burden on system resources, but the fact that a lot of the time the GPU and CPU are talking only to each other, via extremely high-bandwidth, low-latency connections and caches on the die, means a lot of the traffic doesn't even leave the socket.

One theoretical way in which an integrated GPU *might* reduce the performance of the CPU is due to thermal limiting. If the GPU forces the die to reach high temperatures then the CPU may be throttled to reduce temperatures. Other than that I doubt an integrated GPU can measurably reduce the CPU's performance.

Answer (score 2):

On older chipsets (P4 era, some core2duo's) you are right. These are bandwidth starved and integrating a GPU on the same die as the CPU will reduce CPU performance.

On more modern systems there no longer is a FSB (see @Lunatik's answer which is very good in that regard) and CPU performance decrease due to shared bandwidth to the memory should be minimal.

However:

- It does use on die space, which means less space for a CPU. In other words, you could have had a faster CPU with the same amount of silicon.
- It does produce heat. Which might mean less overhead for turbo'ing.
- But also: It is cheaper to use an APU or a die with CPU and GPU than a separate CPU and a dedicated GPU. While this is only relevant for people who do not use a dedicated GPU it does save costs. And if the onboard GPU is fast enough for most people then it makes economical sense to build these.

Two more notes:

> But this technology gets put on all newer desktop Intel CPUs.
>   What am I missing?

For most users:

1. Cheaper to integrate (for the chip builders)
2. Faster to integrate (hence the whole AMD APU idea).
3. Sensible for most users (office use, families who just mail or use social media).
4. Possibly not economically sensible to build two lines of CPU's. One with GPU part and one without (though I guess only Intel can confirm this).

Note that memory access might not limit a CPU too much thanks to its caches. But it can limit the on-board GPU die. Hence the 4th level cache on Intel chips with Iris graphics. Ditto for AMD where higher speeds RAM means much better APU-gaming performance.